# I want to post days only instead of datepicker

Tags: reactjs

I want to post days in place of datepicker in the column of table.when 
    I post the datepicker in the table of column, it should be converted 
    into days.For example when i post date of today, it should show 1 day 
    in the table of column, 2 days for tommorow and so on. [the screenshot 
    of my project is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT5uy.png).how to solve this problem so please help me out.

the code of my project look like this.it only post date only not days.

```
const datetime = new Date(2016, 8, 20);
export default class SupportInterface extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super (props);
this.state = {
  active: false,
  socket: null,
  timestampBalance:datetime,
  supportInfo: [],
  modalComapnyName:'',
  modalVehicleNo:'',
  modalSimNo:'',
  modalLat: '27.931963',
  modalLng: '84.85758'

}
```

this code post the date from form.

```
 saveForm(){ 
axios({
method:'post',
url: 'https://something.something.com.np/updateRechargeStatus',
data:{
  timestamp:moment(this.state.timestampBalance).format("MMM DD,         YYYY"),
  balance: '51',
  sim_number:this.state.modalSimNo
}
})
.then((response)=>{
  if(response.data.success){
  this.setState({
    active:false
  });
  this.getSupportInfo();
}else{
  alert("unable to update balance");

}
})
.catch((error)=>{
throw('error',error);
});
}
```

i am using bootstrap table to show the date like this

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField="timestamp_for_balance" dataSort={true}>Recharge date</TableHeaderColumn>
```

the datepicker form is like this.

```
 <DatePicker label='Date'  onChange={(text) => this.setState({timestampBalance: text})} value={this.state.timestampBalance} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Picking up on an old question here: You can use the [difference function in moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
var a = moment(this.state.timestampBalance);
var b = moment();
a.diff(b, 'days') //number of days between today and timestampBalanceDate
```

And since if you want today to be 1 just add 1 to the diff.